# Can I use TypeScript overloads when using fat arrow syntax for class methods?

Tags: typescript, arrow-functions

I've converted some classes from the conventional form:

```
class TestOverloads {
    private status = "blah";
    public doStuff(selector: JQuery);
    public doStuff(selector: string);
    public doStuff(selector: any) {
        alert(this.status);
    }
}
```

to use arrow function expressions instead:

```
class TestOverloads2 {
    private status = "blah";
    public doStuff = (selector: any) => {
        alert(this.status);
    }
}
```

so as to avoid scoping problems when the class methods are used in a callback (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627138/typescript-this-scoping-issue-when-called-in-jquery-callback) for background).

I can't work out how to recreate my overloaded function signatures though. How would I write my overloads when using the fat arrow?

Comment: Do not use fat arrow for methods. It will become a property of the class, not a prototype method.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can write an inline type literal for the call signatures the function supports:

```
class TestOverloads2 {
    private status = "blah";
    public doStuff: {
        (selector: JQuery): void;
        (selector: string): void;
    } = (selector: any) => {
        alert(this.status);
    }
}
```

That's sort of hideous, so you might want to extract it into an interface instead:

```
interface SelectByJQueryOrString {
    (selector: JQuery): void;
    (selector: string): void;
}

class TestOverloads3 {
    private status = "blah";
    public doStuff: SelectByJQueryOrString = (selector: any) => {
        alert(this.status);
    }
}
```

Comment: The interface type annotation is a great idea.

Comment: Note: In learning about this, I came across this TS Dos and Donts: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html At the bottom of the page in the Use Union Types section, it mentions using unions for single-position overloads. So in this example, it would be `selector: JQuery|string): void` for the definition. I am wondering tho, should the actual instance also be a union instead of `any`? - `... = (selector: JQuery|string) => { alert...`

Comment: If I try this syntax, without named interface properties, it throws an error in the implementing class saying it incorrectly implements the interface (no signature match).

Comment: As @user4275029 mentions, you should use a union. But to be clear: you should use a union INSTEAD OF an overload. So delete the overload and do `public doStuff = (selector: JQuery | string) => {...}`

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit of a technicality, but you are no longer creating a function, you are creating a property (that happens to be a function).

You could solve your problem using naming rather than overloading though.

```
class TestOverloads2 {
    private status = "blah";
    public doStuffWithSelector = (selector: string) => {
        alert(this.status);
    }
    public doStuffWithJqueryObject = (jqo: JQuery) => {
        alert(this.status);
    }
}
```

If there is significant duplication, you can put that in a common function that both named functions call, for example: `this.sharedStuff()`.