# Overloading an arrow function

Tags: typescript

I can do this:

```js
export function changeParameter(parameter: Parameters.booleanParameter, value: boolean): ChangeParameterAction
export function changeParameter(parameter: Parameters.stringParameter, value: boolean): ChangeParameterAction
// ... more types

export function changeParameter(parameter: Parameters, value: any): ChangeParameterAction {
  return { type: PARAMETER_CHANGED, parameter, value };
};
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to do the following without getting any errors (including changing the declarations to similar arrow functions but I so don't know how to do that right that I'm not pasting any examples.

```js
const changeParameter = (parameter: Parameters, value: any): ChangeParameterAction => ({ type: PARAMETER_CHANGED, parameter, value })
```

Is there a way to do this? (Also is there any shorter way to construct this overload without listing all the combinations separately?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript overload arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187614/typescript-overload-arrow-functions)

Comment: It seems your return type is always the same `ChangeParameterAction`, so you could just combine your function argument types as union like `const changeParameter = (parameter: Parameters.booleanParameter | Parameters.stringParameter, value: boolean): ChangeParameterAction => {...}`. If that still doesn't help, please provide all types in the example, so we can help better.