# Function overloading in typescript throw error

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand how function overloading in typescript works.

```js
type CreateElement = {
  (tag: 'a'): HTMLAnchorElement
  (tag: 'canvas'): HTMLCanvasElement
  (tag: 'table'): HTMLTableElement
}

let createElement: CreateElement = (tag: 'a' | 'canvas' | 'table') => {
  if (tag === 'a') return new HTMLAnchorElement()
  if (tag === 'canvas') return new HTMLCanvasElement()
  if (tag === 'table') return new HTMLTableElement()
  throw new Error('wrong tag');
}
```

The code above throws the error:

```
Type 'HTMLAnchorElement | HTMLCanvasElement | HTMLTableElement' is not assignable to type 'HTMLAnchorElement'.
    Type 'HTMLCanvasElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLAnchorElement': charset, coords, download, hreflang, and 21 more.
```

I have ensured that I resolve the parameter `tag` before returning the appropriate type for a given `tag` type. Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: Wouldn't `CreateElement` be `type CreateElement = HTMLAnchorElement | HTMLCanvasElement | HTMLTableElement`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I'm overloading the function by taking union of function signature but you're referring to union of objects.

Answer (score 1):

[Function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) can only be used with function declarations.

Workarounds with "overloaded" (arrow) function expressions may work in a [limited, weak typed way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187614/typescript-overload-arrow-functions). But unlike the former, the compiler does not have a special treatment for these expressions. So they will not behave in the manner you expect it (your code error is already a good example).

Your rewritten example with proper function overloads looks like this:

```
function createElement(tag: 'a'): HTMLAnchorElement // overload 1
function createElement(tag: 'canvas'): HTMLCanvasElement // 2
function createElement(tag: 'table'): HTMLTableElement // 3 
function createElement(tag: 'a' | 'canvas' | 'table') { // fn implementation
    if (tag === 'a') return new HTMLAnchorElement()
    if (tag === 'canvas') return new HTMLCanvasElement()
    if (tag === 'table') return new HTMLTableElement()
    throw new Error('wrong tag');
}

const ret = createElement("a") // HTMLAnchorElement
```

Comment: I see...this works. Only drawback is the need to repeat the function name compared to function expression.

Comment: yeah, I also like the leaner arrow function syntax a bit more (and you can declare function interface types for them). But this one will provide stronger types for the function implementation. So I would prefer it anytime.