# How can I document overloading arrow functions in Typescript / TSDoc?

Tags: typescript, tsdoc

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53143568/676342) I know how to type an overloaded error function:

```
type IOverload = {
    (param:number):number[];
    (param:object):object[];
}

const overloadedArrowFunc:IOverload = (param:any) => {
    return [param,param];
}

let val = overloadedArrowFunc(4);
```

But how do I *document* it using TSDoc? I've tried adding documentation blocks above the individual typings in the `type`, but no dice.