# Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics, react-tsx

I'm refactoring a JS code into TS (actually jsx/tsx) and I'm facing a problem with functions.

To simplify the issue... let's suppose I get this function "**checkIt**", which can receive a string or number as parameter and returns a boolean.

This is the JS function:

```
const FIRST_ROW = 'Initial';
const SECOND_ROW = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4]);

const checkIt = id => {
if (FIRST_ROW.includes(id) || SECOND_ROW.includes(id)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Here is my trial... (as I'm learning TS, I like to declare inferred variables to be consistent)

```
const FIRST_ROW: string = 'Initial';
const SECOND_ROW: Set<number> = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4]);

const checkIt = <T,>(id: T): boolean => {
  if (FIRST_ROW.includes(id) || SECOND_ROW.includes(id)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

This gets me an error on my my "id" references inside the function: *Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'* (or *'number'*).
I've tried using function expression, the Union *string | number* (as explained [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types)), different forms of writing Generics, and Overloads (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53143568/10264581) and I just can't make it work.

Any help here??
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using type casting? Just to hint the compiler:

```
const FIRST_ROW: string = 'Initial';
const SECOND_ROW: Set<number> = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4]);

const checkIt = (id: string | number): boolean => {
  if (FIRST_ROW.includes(id as string) || SECOND_ROW.has(id as number)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAYgSQEoGUAqB9JB5A6gLhmgCcBLMAcxgF4YByBMUqUgQwBs6BuAWAChQkWCgCiAYWwA5ACJY8hFAFMoAHjABXALYAjRcQB8NGGEUB3GEqgAKANoBGADQwATE4DMTgCwBdAJS8+fkFoGGAAC0VgAGsEWForUgATQhJyKgAfYy1dYl9CbRAQdkVWMBpDAG9+GBhSADMYK0RUTBxcADpyYHZ1RMUIBMSYVggiKDJKXxh0zNEJGTkOsJHB4dGNHT1fKaq+GpriZXViMvH1RQCagF9qmEOoY7K6jggL-iugA)

Also, `Set` does not have an `include` method.

To make it completely appropriate you first check if it's really a string. Because you use the union `string|number` the compiler knows that if `typeof id === 'string'` returns false, then `id` has to be a `number`, so casting is not necessary:

```
const FIRST_ROW: string = 'Initial';
const SECOND_ROW: Set<number> = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4]);

const checkIt = (id: string | number): boolean =>
  typeof id === 'string' ? FIRST_ROW.includes(id) : SECOND_ROW.has(id)
;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAYgSQEoGUAqB9JB5A6gLhmgCcBLMAcxgF4YByBMUqUgQwBs6BuAWAChQkWCgCiAYWwA5ACJY8hFAFMoAHjABXALYAjRcQB8NGGEUB3GEqgAKANoBGADQwATE4DMTgCwBdAJS8+fkFoGGAAC0VgAGsEWForUgATQhJyKgAfYy1dYl9CbRAQdkVWMBp9fhgYKABPAAdFEAAzGCSaalo6VMo6GAB+eGR0OVwAOnJgdnVExQgExN8YBXEpWRwxsNY5pN9+LiA)

Comment: Great! Thanks. About the *Set.includes* it was an error while writing it down here. 

Comment: One question though @Poul ... Is it normal in TS to use plenties of *typeof* to constrain types? I've seen on the docs the use of it, but it didn´t sound natural to me, as it looked like I was overflowing my code with more text and logic that could be avoided with another way more simple and elegant...

Comment: @Анна if you have a union parameter, then you should definitely check before doing :)