# Overloading a react callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, overloading

I'm trying to strictly type a hook's return callback.

- If `InputType` wasn't specified, no input is required when function is called and should complain if any input was provided.
- If an `InputType` was specified, it should expect that input type and complain if its not the specified type.

Example

```
 // overload attempts
 async function someFnAsyncCB(): void;
 async function someFnAsyncCB<InputType>(input: InputType): void;

function useSomeFnHook<InputType = undefined>() {
 const [reactiveVar, setReactiveVar] = useState("");
 // ...
 const someFnAsync = useCallback(
  async function someFnAsyncCB<InputType>(input?: InputType): void {
   // ...
  },
  [reactiveVar, etc],
 );
 return someFnAsync;
}
```

My implementation works except for when someFnAsync is not called with an input yet InputType is specified with some type other than undefined. Typescript should complain that I didn't supply it an input value.

I tried overloading the function but Typescript doesn't associate the new overload function with the original function.

How would I go about achieving my initial goals?

Comment: Maybe using `type` or `interface` to type the function will work - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53143568/11145447.

Comment: @programmerRaj How should I alter it to meet my goals?

Comment: Why is the function `someFnAsyncCB` generic? Why do you need the `someFnAsyncCB<InputType>(input: InputType): void` and not just `someFnAsyncCB(input: any): void`?

Comment: @programmerRaj To strictly type check it. I don't want invalid inputs to be accepted.

Comment: Is `InputType` a type?

Comment: @programmerRaj Yes

Answer (score -1):

You are using a generic type when you don't need a generic type.

Replace

```
async function someFnAsyncCB<InputType>(input: InputType): void;
```

with

```
async function someFnAsyncCB(input: InputType): void;
```

The modified hook will look like this:

```
function useSomeFnHook<InputType = undefined>() {
 const [reactiveVar, setReactiveVar] = useState("");
 // ...
 const someFnAsync = useCallback(
                              // No <Generic>
  async function someFnAsyncCB(input?: InputType): void {
   // ...
  },
  [reactiveVar, etc],
 );
 return someFnAsync;
}
```

Documentation about generics: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Comment: I was using generics for `someFnAsyncCB` when I was trying to overload the function. This solution doesn't resolve my issues.

Comment: @SILENT Why do you need to overload the function?

Comment: Because of "My implementation works except for when someFnAsync is not called with an input yet InputType is specified with some type other than undefined. Typescript should complain that I didn't supply it an input value."