# How to change the return type of a function based on an optional parameter being provided?

Tags: typescript

I need to create a function that returns `number` if an optional value is provided, and `number | null` if not.

So far I've tried:

```
type GetValueFn = {
    (values: { defaultValue: number }): number | null;
    (values: { defaultValue: undefined }): number;
}

const getValue: GetValueFn = ({ defaultValue }) => {
    const randomValue = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)
    
    if (randomValue !== 5) return randomValue;
    if (defaultValue !== undefined) return defaultValue;
    return null;
}
```

But I get an error saying:

> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'

What's the correct way of doing this?

[demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwDUCGAbArhAYgOygXigG8AoKMqACgDdUMBnALiKgBMIAzJNFRWiJ7GgC2AIwgAnKAF8AlAOFjJAHyiCUKANyly1Po2ZtO3Xun5Q02QwEtsEFtLmqFErVOLEAxgHtsdYFABzeGRTJjgTDBx8SkJWDi4eEIwHfAA+Im0yb19-cSRLLyEk6AIAWSRgAAsAOg8IKxQKcqrqvIKhChkoACooAEYABhlMqBGrdko2lkLiqABCPAIAVi7xeDRxXCmZvi1yKHHKQwSI6AWCC2tbFlX1zbijRN2RteAN3DVNYikgA)

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use only one definition.

`?` = undefined

```
type GetValueFn = (values: { defaultValue?: number }): number | null;

const getValue: GetValueFn = ({ defaultValue }) => {
    const randomValue = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)
    
    if (randomValue !== 5) return randomValue;
    if (!defaultValue) return defaultValue;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: My intention is for the return type to change if `defaultValue` is provided or not.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, function overloads in typescript still doesn't work correctly for arrow functions. [more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187614/typescript-overload-arrow-functions) I don't know if this is still accurate. If you have the option to, you can declare the function like and it'll work correctly.

```
interface Values {
    defaultValue: number;
}

function getValue(values: Values) : number;
function getValue(values: Partial<Values>) : number | null;
function getValue(values: Values | Partial<Values>) {
    const randomValue = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)
    
    if (randomValue !== 5) return randomValue;
    if (values.defaultValue !== undefined) return values.defaultValue;
    return null;
}
```

Working in [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=5&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDYFcIGdkDeAUMqcgCYTxYZjrYQBcyIWAtgEbQDcRAvkSIwsIBGGAB7EMgDmEOphwAKAG6K8zejlwBKZM1aceQkWMnS5ChqvW5mABThRxmADxa8APj0H2XKMgAPiw0GLzCouJSsvIeNgx2aLZByI7OwG4euN6EJGQIUrhgyFBwIOQSbB7IALzIALJwYAAWAHRIwBhKjS2tpeWVSnoAVMgAjAAMOnmkM8jAMMhK-RVV6sgAhDV1AKx6UPJYUNIrlR68ZPOL8dqtlNS01Vt1IvegEOT7h8fIagl3VDgNCsOAuZAOYCO0lYGDC-EEBRARWQcFqMRBECUBAogOBHmYO2QfB0vERyI4aMscWx9yBj3UzFeVHe5CJJIRhWKtLxmDRACYJij8IZ-CkmTAWaTOcgEJTYuosTiHhjmNz6Rg2bwOUjilTbMxiJcbhokgkdL4jFAwaRjYk0i4MO5bN4LaLgjC4Xw0ba9DVPLlLmTiqc1gw0T02h0uhG%20mVVkNkKNJtNLnMFksQ09tsg9iVvic42d1Narks-rc1RjNtnxSyvpCfuW8ADlec5hCoSFYbw%20EA)

**Edit:** [Updated demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=51&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDYFcIGdkDeAUMqcgCYTxYZjrYQBcyIWAtgEbQDcRAvkVCRYiFAHEIdTDlwAxEIRJkAFADdpeZvRkBKZq048lpNRtzMACnChhgmADza8APj0t2XKMgA%207jBl4BIgQAexBcMGQAc0knc2QJKQY5BQBeZFNk5jgQAE8dZFTnRTJkUPDIqBzyELYnQuQAWTgwAAsAOiRgDGVmtvaqkBq2ZQKAKmQARgAGHWNkeeAYDMHh%20oBCVPSAVgKoSSwoBVXap15SpYz1ZPbKaloNreQsIapQCHI9g6Pka5lbqhwGhJHDnMj7MCHBSsfyBYJhCLIOANGIgvDKAgUQHApzMbbIPg6XjlREcFGxMwYrH3NHMF53d7kAlEojwirUoEPTANABM0yR%20AMnh8z1eMEZxIRkQQ5LRuCpd05tI5OO5hO4QA)

Comment: This looks promising, but the arrow function in your demo seems to still get the same error, and I couldn't fix it.

Comment: If you really need to use arrow functions, you have to use `any` on the function definition. It's not as clean but it'll have to do. You will still get the type correctly when you call the function. But the function declaration will lose the type. Check the updated demo.