# Can I pick type of return data by argument in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

can we predict types by function argument passed to it ?

Let's imagine we have fn that will accept one argument (number) and depends on that number I will return collection or single entity from database. Result will differ in model slightly and I would tell to TypeScript that if such number passed to fn argument exists, return me model A otherwise return me model B.

Fn example:

```
const fn = (id?: number) => {
  // body of fn
}

const myCollectionData = fn(); // interface A
const mySingleRecordData = fn(1); // interface B
```

Cheers!

Comment: Search typescript generics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can declare [overloads for that function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```
const fn: {
  (): interfaceA;
  (id: number): interfaceB;
} = (id?: number) => {
  // body of fn
};
```

(see [Typescript overload arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39187614/1048572) for this particular syntax)