Function with optional argument depending on function's generic type
I'm trying to implement a minimalistic type-safe function that does HTTP requests against a typed server API, but am struggling with the types. Specifically, how to make the third argument (the HTTP request payload) optional for the GET and DELETE requests, while having it verified and non-optional for POST and PUT.
A simplified example (TypeScript playground):
export type Method = 'GET' | 'DELETE' | 'POST' | 'PUT'

// attempt 1:
const httpRequest1 = <M, D>(method: M, url: string, data?: D) =>
  'not implemented yet' as any


// attempt 2:
type HttpRequest <M extends Method, D, R=unknown> = M extends 'GET' | 'DELETE'
  ? (method: M, url: string) => Promise<R>
  : (method: M, url: string, data: D) => Promise<R>

const httpRequest2: HttpRequest = (method, url, data) =>
  'not implemented yet' as any


// expected usage:
interface Data {
  title: string;
}
httpRequest<'POST', Data>('POST', '/', { title: 'test' }) // should typecheck
httpRequest<'POST', Data>('POST', '/', { titleoops: 'test' }) // should NOT typecheck
httpRequest<'POST', Data>('POST', '/') // should NOT typecheck
httpRequest<'GET', undefined>('GET', '/') // should typecheck

I never get all four conditions to typecheck as expected at the same time. At least one is always broken.
Edit: If you're wondering, the full use-case, updated with the working solution.

You can use function overloads.
You make one function that can handle any case at runtime, then give it a number of type declarations that act as the different overloads.
export type Method = 'GET' | 'DELETE' | 'POST' | 'PUT'

function httpRequest(method: 'GET' | 'DELETE', url: string, data?: Data): any;
function httpRequest(method: 'POST' | 'PUT', url: string, data: Data): any;
function httpRequest(method: Method, url: string, data?: Data) {
  return 'not implemented yet' as any
}

// expected usage:
interface Data {
  title: string;
}
httpRequest('POST', '/test', { title: 'test' }) // should typecheck
httpRequest('POST', '/test', { titleoops: 'test' }) // should not  typecheck
httpRequest('POST', '/test') // should not  typecheck
httpRequest('GET', '/test') // should typecheck

At the call site, TS will make sure your arguments match with one of the overloads.

thanks, that works! I had tried that in a variation of attempt 2 as well, but couldn't get it to work with arrow functions and generics (link). does it only work with the function keyword?

@mb21 you will have to define an interface if you want to overload arrow functions, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53143568/112968

Instead of function overloads you could use a spread syntax:
export type Method = 'GET' | 'DELETE' | 'POST' | 'PUT'

const httpRequest = async<D, R = D, M extends Method = Method>
  (...[method, url, data]: M extends 'GET' | 'DELETE' ? [M, string]: [M, string, D]): Promise<R> => {
    return {} as R;
};

// expected usage:
interface Data {
  title: string;
}

httpRequest<Data>('POST', '/test', { title: 'test' }) // should typecheck
httpRequest<Data>('POST', '/test', { titleoops: 'test' }) // should not  typecheck
httpRequest<Data>('POST', '/test') // should not  typecheck
httpRequest<Data>('GET', '/test') // should typecheck

Playground

thanks, that's a good trick as well I'll keep in mind!
