# typescript overload method with arrow function

Tags: typescript, overloading, arrow-functions

anyone know how to use method overload on arrow function?

```
foo(args: string): string
    foo(args: number): number
    foo(args: string | number): string | number {
        if (typeof args === "string") {
            return "string"
        }
        return 1
    }
```

tried this but not working

```
foo: {
    (args: string): string;
    (args: number): number;
} = (args: string | number): string | number => {
    if (typeof args === "string") {
      return "string"
    }
    return 1
}
```

Comment: It can actually support overloading. see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646171/can-i-use-typescript-overloads-when-using-fat-arrow-syntax-for-class-methods

Comment: You can actually overloading an arrow function. see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646171/can-i-use-typescript-overloads-when-using-fat-arrow-syntax-for-class-methods

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arrow functions don't support overloading. From the [language specification](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#4.11):

> The descriptions of function declarations provided in chapter 6 apply to arrow functions as well, except that arrow functions do not support overloading.

When you write

```
foo: {
  (args: string): string;
  (args: number): number;
}
```

then you don't overload. You actually say that `foo` is a function that can take one of these forms (or rather both forms). The arrow function

```
(args: string | number): string | number =>
```

violates that restriction because it's a single function (not an overloaded one) and `string | number` means that you can return a number when a string is expected.

As already proposed by artem changing the return type to `any` or an intersection type solves the problem. But it's not the same as overloading because the compiler doesn't chose between the signatures. You effectively only have one: That of the arrow function.

Comment: but that callable signature for `foo` works the same way as overload - when you call it with `string`, the compiler infers the return type as string, and when you call it with `number`, the return type is number.

Comment: @artem Like an observer effect: If you declare it it's `string & number` but if you use it it's `string` or `number` ;) Unfortunately this construct and its implications are not explained in the specification. But yes: The effect is the same.

Answer (score 6):

For reasons I don't fully understand, the return type of the implementation is expected to be intersection, not union:

```
class B {
    foo: {
        (args: string): string;
        (args: number): number;
    } = (args: string | number): string & number => {
        if (typeof args === "string") {
            return "string" as string & number;
        }
        return 1 as string & number;
    }    
}
```

So it's no better than just declaring the implementation to return `any`, as they do in [documentation examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
class B {
    foo: {
        (args: string): string;
        (args: number): number;
    } = (args: string | number): any => {
        if (typeof args === "string") {
            return "string";
        }
        return 1;
    }    
}
```