# Adaptable function that can return undefined if input is undefined

Tags: typescript, undefined, typescript-generics

If have a TypeScript function `f: A => B`. However I in my applications the input may be undefined, so I always have to write, say, `const b?: B = a && f(a);`.

Can I change the function to include the check within the function (i.e., something like
`(a: A | undefined) => B | undefined = (a => a && …)` but typed so that the return type does not contain undefined if a cannot be undefined, so that I can write either `const b: B = f(a)` if a cannot be undefined, and `const b?: B = f(a)` if a can be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is doable with [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```js
// these are the two overloads
function f(x: number): string;
function f(x: number | undefined): string | undefined;

// this is the implementation, its type signature is not visible
function f(x: number | undefined): string | undefined {
  return x?.toString();
}
```

Using the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20646171/5923139), it can be extended to arrow functions:

```js
const f: {
  // these are the two overloads
  (x: number): string;
  (x: number | undefined): string | undefined;
} = 
  // this is the implementation, its type signature is not visible
  // not sure why arrow functions make typescript dumber but "any" is now necessary as the return type
  (x: number | undefined): any => x?.toString();
```

Comment: Nice! Can it also be done with functions defined as `const f = (a: A)=>B…`?