# Output function type depended on argument type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a fat-arrow function, that will return:

- string, if the argument is a number,
- number, if the argument is a string.

This is my code so far:

```js
type ToString = (input: number) => string
type ToNumber = (input: string) => number
type Converter = ToString | ToNumber

const convert: Converter = <T extends number | string>(val: T) => null as any // The function body is not important.

const x = convert(7) // Error: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. (2345)
```

Unfortunately, the code above doesn't work because of the mentioned error message on the last line. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Is this just a typo?  You want `type Converter = ToString & ToNumber`, as it is both a `ToString` *and* a `ToNumber`.  [Like this](https://tsplay.dev/WK7ZpW). If you write `ToString | ToNumber` it means that `convert` could be one *or* the other and you can't call it unless you know which one, or you manage to pass in a parameter that would work regardless, meaning a `number` *and* a `string`, or `number & string` which is impossible and reduces to `never`.

Comment: If this is not just a typo then I can write up an answer explaining why you want an intersection of call signatures (equivalent to an overload) instead of a union of call signatures (which can be [called](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) but only with an intersection of function parameters).  Of course you can also make a single generic/conditional call signature, but that might be out of scope for the question.  Let me know what you want to see here.

Comment: See [Typescript overload arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187614/typescript-overload-arrow-functions) and [Can I use TypeScript overloads when using fat arrow syntax for class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20646171/12299000)

Answer (score 2):

Define it as generic type:

```js
type Converter = <T extends string | number>(input: T) => T extends string ? number : string;

const convert: Converter = <T extends string | number>(val: T): T extends string ? number : string => null as any; // The function body is not important.
```

Or use [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```js
function convert(val: string): number;
function convert(val: number): string;
function convert(val: string | number) {
  return null as any;
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `type Converter = <T extends string | number>(input: T) => T extends string ? number : string;` because number returns string and vice vers

Comment: Oh, thanks. updated.