# TypeScript "this" pointer doesn't work with promises? "Unable to get property X of undefined or null reference"

Tags: typescript, promise, q

Suppose I have a TypeScript class that makes use of another class instance. The outer class has a method that returns a promise, using the [Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/) (but I can repro the same issue with WinJS, as well).

```
class OuterClass {
    private helper = new InternalHelper();
    doSomething() : Q.Promise<any> {
        this.helper.doSomething();
        return Q("Returned promise");
    }
}

class InternalHelper {
    doSomething() {
        alert("Hello");
    }
}
```

To use the code, I would run something like:

```
var outer = new OuterClass();
Q("Hello, World!")
    .then(outer.doSomething)
    .fail(function(e) {
        alert("Failed due to " + e);
    })
    .done()
```

The problem: Running this code results in "Failed due to TypeError: Unable to get property 'doSomething' of undefined or null reference".

Looking at this under the debugger, it appears that the "this" pointer inside of OuterClass's "doSomething" method is NOT the pointer to OuterClass.  But I'm unclear how to fix this.

Interestingly, the code does run if instead of

```
.then(outer.doSomething)
```

I use

```
.then(function() {
    return outer.doSomething();
})
```

But obviously, the ".then(outer.doSomething)" syntax is shorter, and doesn't require remembering to do a "return".

Any ideas what might be going on here? Is this a bug? And if so, is it a bug in TypeScript or in Q?

Thanks!

===================================

**Update/Answer based on comment from Ryan Cavanaugh:**

For the scenario I was looking for, looks like the best option appears to modify OuterClass to expose the method as a variable rather than a function (e.g., "Automatic Class Binding" in Ryan's response [on another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627138/typescript-this-scoping-issue-when-called-in-jquery-callback))

The OuterClass definition needs to change to:

```
class OuterClass {
    private helper = new InternalHelper();
    public doSomething = () => {
        this.helper.doSomething();
        return Q("Returned promise");
    }
}
```

This allows for the method to be called without the caller needing to use a lambda. It can be called just using:

```
.then(outer.doSomething)
```

Thanks, Ryan!

===================================

Comment: Update: I tried this with WinJS promises, same issue. So I think the underlying problem is with the way that the TypeScript code is generated, and the different semantic of "this".  But I'm still unsure how to work around this...

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627138/typescript-this-scoping-issue-when-called-in-jquery-callback

Comment: It's not a bug, promises always have "this" set to undefined - you can and should use an arrow to overcome this: .then(() => outer.doSomething()), you can also use bluebird which supports this

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh, thanks for the pointer and your awesome answer on that other question.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, thanks for confirming that this is a by design behavior. All the same, from an API-caller perspective, I think it's best to expose the method as something that can be "just passed in" without having to remember to do the () => outer.doSomething() syntax (it's a subtle enough difference that it's easy to forget).  I've updated the question based on Ryan Cavenaugh's on the other thread -- I think it gives usability for the API that OuterClass exposes. Thanks anyway, though!

Comment: This is how JavaScript works as a language - you might hate dynamic this (I'm not a huge fan) but it's a fundamental part of the language - just like if you do the following in Chrome it won't work `var log = console.log; log(15)`

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky The expected behavior you're describing is impossible. When you pass `outer.doSomething` into a function, the function receiving it has no way of knowing that `doSomething` was a property on some object `outer` and that it should use that as the calling context. All it can do is call the function that it receives. This is true _any_ time you pass a function around in Java/TypeScript, not just with Promises. The arrow function allows you to overcome this by binding `this` to the function.

Comment: More about `this` : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Comment: @basarat, great explanation in the video. I highly recommend that other folks who run into this problem watch this.