# How do I maintain the 'correct' scope in javascript even listeners?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm writing a geometry engine in Typescript, and I'm trying to implement drag&drop. I have a point object that inherets from a geometry object, and it has control of a `circle` element inside an `svg` element. I have a `mousedown` even listener attached to the circle element that calls a function belonging to the point object, a little like this:

```
class point extends geometry {
    htmlNode:any;
    constructor() {
        this.htmlNode = makeTheThing();
        addItToTheDom();
        this.htmlNode.addEventListener("mmousedown",this.onClick);
        onClick();
    }

    onClick() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

When the page loads it outputs the point object to the console, but when I click it outputs the html element, rather than the javascript object. Previously I got around this like this:

```
class point extends geometry {
    htmlNode:any;
    constructor() {
        this.htmlNode = makeTheThing();
        addItToTheDom();
        var blah = this;
        var f = function() {
            console.log(blah);
        }
        this.htmlNode.addEventListener("mmousedown",f);
        f();
    }

    onClick() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

*That* will give the javascript object when it loads and when I click, but it's ugly and I'd like to do it more cleanly.

UPDATE: For anyone who cares, I did end up just rewriting this, much prettier now.

Comment: Try `this.htmlNode.addEventListener("mmousedown",f.bind(this));`. It might be that `this` gets assigned to the htmlNode again though.

Comment: @Halcyon This works and is much prettier, but it also feels a little hackey to me, I'll use this until I find something better

Comment: So, by default `this` in the event callback will be set to the DOM node that handled the event.  YOU have to decide what you want `this` to be.  If that's what you want, then you can save `this` to a local variable in scope before assigning the event handler so you can access that value that way.  If you want `this` to be your own object, then use `.bind()` to set it yourself.  Those are two of the main options.

Comment: wink wink : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627138/typescript-this-scoping-issue-when-called-in-jquery-callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pure JavaScript (ES5), you can use `bind` to create a new function that will have function context (`this`) forever bound:

```
this.htmlNode.addEventListener("mmousedown",this.onClick.bind(this));
```

In TypeScript (and shortly in ES6) we have arrow functions:

```
this.htmlNode.addEventListener("mmousedown", event => this.onClick(event));
```

Arrow functions maintain a lexical this, that is, the take `this` from surrounding context.

Comment: I've hacked together a fairly terrible solution with this technique, and I'm sure the only way to make this work well is a total restructuring of my program. I need to learn me some real OOP...

Answer (score 0):

in pure js i would do it this way (of course without 'class'^^):

```
class point extends geometry {
var parent = this;
var htmlNode = null;
this.constructor = function() {
    parent.htmlNode = makeTheThing();
    parent.htmlNode.addEventListener(yourStuff);
}

this.onClick = function() {
    console.log(parent);
}
```

}

maybe there is a better way in ts, but this should work