# update instance of a class that contains an onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, typescript

I have a typescript class myClass with an array instance:

```
module myModule {
    export class myClass {

        arrayElements: Array<string>;

...
}
}
```

and in this class I have a function `myfunction()` where I create a button and I handle click event:

```
function myfunction(){
...
var button = (<HTMLButtonElement>document.createElement("BUTTON"));


            button.onclick = function () {
                // something
            }
...
}
```

in "something" I'd like to update my array instance (i.e. push a string), but I don't know how. If I try

```
this.arrayElements.push("example");
```

When I click on button (in .html page) I have this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

most likely because "this" is instance of HTMLButtonElement.

If I try with

```
myClass.prototype.arrayElements.push("example");
```

I have the same error. Is there a way to realize my purpose?

Comment: You need to capture the `this` in a closure.

Comment: @SLaks can you provide an example?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627138/typescript-this-scoping-issue-when-called-in-jquery-callback