# Passing class method as parameter in Typescript

Tags: typescript, function, parameters

I'm searching for a possibility to pass a class-method to a function which then can execute that function on an instance of that class.
Something like that pseudocode: (note that this is an abstract example)

```
class Foo {
    public somefunc() {
        // do some
    }
    public anyfunc() {
        // do any
    }
}

function bar(obj: Foo ,func: "Foo.method") {  // "that's what im looking for"
    obj.func();
}

bar(new Foo(), Foo.somefunc);  // do some
bar(new Foo(), Foo.anyfunc);  // do any
```

Is there a possiblity to do this?

I know i could be doing something like that:

```
class Foo {
    static somefunc(fooObj: Foo) {
        // do some
    }
    static anyfunc(fooObj: Foo) {
        // do any
    }
}

interface func {
    (fooObj: Foo);
}

function bar(obj: Foo, fn: func) {
    fn(obj);
}

bar(new Foo(), Foo.somefunc);  // do some
bar(new Foo(), Foo.anyfunc);  // do any
```

but that involves static functions which I don't want.

Answer (score 35):

This doesn't compile-time check that the function came from a `Foo`, but does the rest:

```
class Foo {
    public somefunc() {
        // do some
    }
    public anyfunc() {
        // do any
    }
}

function bar(obj: Foo ,func: () => void) {
    func.call(obj);
}

bar(new Foo(), Foo.prototype.somefunc);  // do some
bar(new Foo(), Foo.prototype.anyfunc);  // do any
```

Comment: what is the name of this pattern?

Answer (score 21):

## Typescript 2+ solution

**TL;DR**: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20result%3A%20number%20%3D%2042%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20func(this%3A%20Foo)%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.result%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20action()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Hello%20world!%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20bar(callbackFn%3A%20(this%3A%20void)%20%3D%3E%20any%2C%20thisArg%3F%3A%20undefined)%3A%20any%3B%0D%0Afunction%20bar%3CT%3E(callbackFn%3A%20(this%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20any%2C%20thisArg%3A%20T)%3A%20any%3B%0D%0Afunction%20bar%3CT%2C%20TResult%3E(callbackFn%3A%20(this%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20TResult%2C%20thisArg%3A%20T)%3A%20TResult%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20callbackFn.call(thisArg)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo%20%3D%20new%20Foo()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Abar(action)%3B%20%2F%2F%20success%0D%0Abar(foo.func)%3B%20%2F%2F%20ERROR%3A%20forgot%20to%20pass%20%60thisArg%60%0D%0Abar(foo.func%2C%20foo)%3B%20%2F%2F%20success), [Repo with a demo](https://github.com/deilan-stackoverflow-samples/typescript-instance-method-as-callback)

Advantages:

1. Compile-time checking.
2. Won't let you lost `this` context when
   passing an instance's method.
3. Don't lose performance: don't have to declare class' methods as instance methods (e. g. `public somefunc = () => { return this.prop; }`) - [Learn more](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3927#issuecomment-123434208).
4. Don't mess with a class's prototype.
5. Consistent signature pattern: passing a callback as the first arg and `thisArg` as the second (e. g. [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)).

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo {
    private result: number = 42;

    public func(this: Foo): number {
        return this.result;
    }
}

function action(): void {
    console.log("Hello world!");
}

function bar(callbackFn: (this: void) => any, thisArg?: undefined): any;
function bar<T>(callbackFn: (this: T) => any, thisArg: T): any;
function bar<T, TResult>(callbackFn: (this: T) => TResult, thisArg: T): TResult {
    return callbackFn.call(thisArg);
}

const foo = new Foo();

bar(action); // success
bar(foo.func); // ERROR: forgot to pass `thisArg`
bar(foo.func, foo); // success
```

Turn your attention to the signature of `Foo#func`:

```
public func(this: Foo): number
```

It states that this function should be invoked in a context of the class' instance. This is the first part of the solution which won't let you lost `this` context.

The second part is `bar` function overloads:

```
function bar(callbackFn: (this: void) => any, thisArg?: undefined): any;
function bar<T>(callbackFn: (this: T) => any, thisArg: T): any;
function bar<T, TResult>(callbackFn: (this: T) => TResult, thisArg: T): TResult
```

This would let you you pass generic functions as well as instance methods.

You can learn more about these topics in TypeScript Handbook:

1. [`this` parameters in callbacks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters)
2. [Function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)
3. [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you're looking for some way for the TypeScript compiler to enforce that the given function exists on Foo?  Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to do that.  Maybe another TypeScript guru can come in here and answer that more concretely, but I'm pretty sure this is the closest that you can get:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(private name:string) { }

    public somefunc() {
        console.log("someFunc called on", this.name);
    }
    public anyfunc() {
        console.log("anyFunc called on", this.name);
    }
}

function bar(obj: Foo, func: string) {
    if (obj[func] && obj[func] instanceof Function) {
        obj[func]();
    } else {
        throw new Error("Function '" + func + "' is not a valid function");
    }
}

bar(new Foo("foo1"), "somefunc");  // output: 'somefunc called on foo1'
bar(new Foo("foo2"), "anyfunc");  // output: 'anyfunc called on foo1'
bar(new Foo("foo3"), "badFunction");  // throws: Error: Function 'badFunction' is not a valid function
```

Comment: You're right, I was hoping in typescript was a way to let the compiler check if that given function exists on the class.
Thanks for the answer though, didn't know that you could call a function of an object like that:  `obj["functionname"]()`

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

Yes, declare function like this:

```
myfunction(action: () => void){
   action();
}
```

Call it like this from typescript:

```
myfunction(() => alert("hello"));
```

Or from javascript:

```
myfunction(function() { alert("hello"); });
```

Also you can pass method:

```
myfunction(this.someMethod);
```

Answer (score 4):

For my part; according to the statement of the problem, I could have done like this:

```js
class Foo {
    public constructor() {
        this.welcome = this.welcome.bind(this)
    }

    public welcome(msg: string): void {
        console.log(`hello ${msg}`)
    }
}

function bar(msg: string, fn: void): void {
    fn(msg)
}

const foo = new Foo()
bar('world', foo.welcome) // 'hello world'
```

In addition, I should point out that I was inspired by [this clear explanation](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9851#issue-233622657).

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 2):

You could use fat arrow functions. They shouldn't lose "this"

```
class Foo {
    public somefunc = () => {
        // do some
    }
    public anyfunc = () => {
        // do any
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use facade design pattern for this case.

When you create a complex library, tool or system,consisting of many functions and/or classes; It gets hard to understand and dependent. So you should implement a class which provides a simple uniform interface.

```
class Foo{

      public somefunc() {
        console.log("some")
      }

      public anyfunc() {
        console.log("any")
      }


    };


    class FuncFacade {

      getFunc(obj: any, func_name: string) {
        switch (func_name) {
          case obj.somefunc.name: {
            return obj.somefunc;
          }

          case obj.anyfunc.name: {
            return obj.anyfunc;
          }
          default: {
            throw new Error("No such func!");
          }

        }
      }
    }

    let ff = new FuncFacade();

    function bar(obj: Foo, func_name: string) {
      ff.getFunc(obj,func_name)();
    }

    bar(new Foo(), Foo.prototype.anyfunc.name);
```

Maybe this was not what you asked for but this is the way how it should be.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript would allow this, but not sure if that is what you want?

```
class Foo {
 public someFunc(name:string){
  return "Hello, " + name;
 }

function bar(funcName: string) {
    return eval(funcName);
}

console.log(bar("new Foo().someFunc('erik')"));
```

Comment: Yeah that would work, but i wouldn't get the benefit of typescript checking if `someFunc()` is actually defined on `Foo`.