# typescript callback from promise and access 'this'

Tags: typescript

Got difficult to figure this. Failed to call this.doA() from the callback of external Promise.

```
class A {
    private _startCallback;

    // register callbacks
    constructor({startCallback}) {
        this._startCallback = startCallback;
    }
   load() {
       // A external promise.
       HelloPromise.get({callbackA: myCallback}).then(...)
   }

   private myCallback() {
      // FAILED to Call doA
      this.doA() 
   }
   private doA() {
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript "this" scoping issue when called in jquery callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627138/typescript-this-scoping-issue-when-called-in-jquery-callback)

Comment: Or any of dozens if not hundreds of other similar questions, which can be found with a google search for something like "javascript method callback this:".

Answer (score 1):

The context of `this` is different when the method `myCallback` is executed.

You have two options:

(1) Using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
HelloPromise.get({ callbackA: () => { this.myCallback(); } }).then(...)
```

(2) Using the [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function:

```
HelloPromise.get({ callbackA: this.myCallback.bind(this) }).then(...)
```

Comment: Well, in any case it has to be `this.myCallback`, right?

Comment: @torazaburo Indeed! missed that part, thanks, I changed the answer