# TypeScript class and JS scope confusion (again)

Tags: javascript, typescript, this

I thought the JS scope can not surprise me ever again but here we are.

I am using this [little JQuery plugin for observer like pattern](https://gist.github.com/dharFr/1928176). 
This is how I *subscribe* and *unsubscribe* a handler (listener) from custom events

```
$.observer.subscribe('my-event', this.myHandler);
$.observer.unsubscribe('my-event', this.myHandler);

public myHandler() {
    console.log("hello World", this);
}
```

The problem is that if I use a class method as a callback (`this.myHandler`) that method will be invoked not within the class scope but within the observer object scope.

When I use JQuery's proxy method like this:

```
$.observer.subscribe('my-event', $.proxy(this.myHandler, this));
$.observer.unsubscribe('my-event', $.proxy(this.myHandler, this));
```

the scope in the handler is correct but the unsubscribe method stops working, apparently with the proxy I am unsubscribing from something else, not the handler method.

I can not use the old JS trick of defining a local variable and use it instead of this, like

```
var o = this;
public myHandler() {
    console.log("hello World", o);
}
```

because this is a typescript class and the var has different meaning.

What should I do?

Comment: Isn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627138/typescript-this-scoping-issue-when-called-in-jquery-callback) - no pun intended - a duplicate? In this particular case I'd use a temporary variable to store the result of `$.proxy` call.

Comment: @raina77ow the arrow function has the same problem as the &.proxy method, the unsubscribe will not work - and I don't understand why.

Comment: @raina77ow sorry, you were right, I was just doing something wrong in my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that this happens is because `$.proxy(this.myHandler, this)` returns *a new function* each time you invoke it.  In order for `unsubscribe` to work you need to pass it the same function that you passed to `subscribe` (this is the case with almost any listener interface, including the DOM ones).

```
const handler = $.proxy(this.myHandler, this);
$.observer.subscribe('my-event', handler);
$.observer.unsubscribe('my-event', handler);
```

Alternatively, you can create your method as an arrow function property in your constructor, or automatically bind it:

```
class YourClass {
  constructor() {
    this.myHandler = () => {};
    // or
    this.myHandler = this.myHandler.bind(this);
  }
}
```

Then you can just pass `this.myHandler` into `observer.subscribe` and it will do the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

What should work is to declare the handler as a property:

```
//public myHandler() {
public myHandler = () => {
    console.log("hello World", this);
}
```

this has a side-effect... `myHandler` is property and cannot be overridden. But we can call another method *(`toBeOverriddenHandler`)* in our handler, which will have proper scope *(`this`)* and could be overridden

```
public myHandler = () => {
    this.toBeOverriddenHandler()
}

// could be changed in subtypes
protected toBeOverriddenHandler () {
    console.log("hello World", this);
}
```