# Get property value from a method in the same class

Tags: typescript, kendo-ui

I've the following class

```
namespace Cancel {
    export class View {
        controller = new Controller();

        test() {
            this.controller.pr();
        }
    }

    export const view = new View();
}
```

I call the test method from a button inside a Telerik KendoUI-Grid row and I get the following error

> Cannot read property 'pr' of undefined at init.test

This error is shown because ***this*** is not pointing to the class so the question is

How can I access to *controller's* property in the *test* method?

Comment: It depends on how it's being called. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627138/typescript-this-scoping-issue-when-called-in-jquery-callback

Comment: Thank you @RyanCavanaugh for pointing me to the solution.