# Typescript AngularJS 'this' is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, scope

I have a service written with TypeScript. Something like:

```
export default class AServiceClass {

    constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService, ...) {}

    method1(data : any) : void {
        this.$http(...)
    }

    method2(data : any) : void {
        this.$http(...)
    }
}
```

And I have a controller class, that utilize this service:

```
export default class AControllerClass {

    constructor(private aService: AServiceClass, ...) {}

    $onInit(){

        let method = true ? this.aService.method1 : this.aService.method2;
        method({ ... data ... });
    }
}
```

Service methods throw an Exception - `this is undefind`. If I use it like `this.aService.method1({ ... data ... })`, all is fine. Ofc I can do `method.bind(aService)({ ... data ... })` or `method.call(aService, { ... data ... })`, but why there is a scope difference?

Thx.

Comment: this.$onInit instead of $ngInit, should work. Not sure angular 1 is already a little bit back for me but try it. this.$onInit = function () { your code };

Comment: Ah, it was a typo in example, ofc $onInit. Thx

Comment: Still it throws "this is undefinded" ?

Comment: Yup, it does...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627138/typescript-this-scoping-issue-when-called-in-jquery-callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `method1` method is invoked without a context so `this` inside it will be undefined. You have to call it with the `aService` object as context or explicitly set the context using `call` or `apply` or explicitly bind the context using `bind`:

```
this.aService.method1(); // `this` will be aService inside `method1`

method.call(aService, args);

method.apply(aService, [args]);

// Or bind using `bind`:

let method = true ? this.aService.method1.bind(this.aService) : this.aService.method2.bind(this.aService);

method();
```