# Reference 'this' is null on $rootScope.$on

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Declared the following constructor in my Typescript AngularJS controller.

```
static $inject: Array<string> = [
    '$rootScope',
    'BookingRepository'
];
constructor(
    $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService,
    bookingRepository: soft.data.BookingRepository
) {
    super();

    this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
    this.$rootScope.$on('accessController_onNavAccessSelected', this.accessController_onNavAccessSelected);

    this.bookingRepository = bookingRepository;
}
```

BUT when accessController_onNavAccessSelected is called, **I'm getting null when I reference 'this'. I'm expecting the instance of the controller.**

```
// Listening Events
accessController_onNavAccessSelected(event: ng.IAngularEvent, accessViewModel: soft.data.AccessViewModel): void {
    console.log(this);
}
```

**What did I missed? Or How do I get a reference on the instance of my controller?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript "this" scoping issue when called in jquery callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627138/typescript-this-scoping-issue-when-called-in-jquery-callback)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The context of the keyword *this* changes when using callbacks.

To prevent that, add *.bind(this)*:

```
this.$rootScope.$on('accessController_onNavAccessSelected', this.accessController_onNavAccessSelected.bind(this));
```

or just use arrow function of ES6:

```js
accessController_onNavAccessSelected = (event: ng.IAngularEvent, accessViewModel: soft.data.AccessViewModel) => {
    console.log(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change `accessController_onNavAccessSelected` declaration this way:

```
accessController_onNavAccessSelected = (event: ng.IAngularEvent, accessViewModel: soft.data.AccessViewModel): void => {
    console.log(this);
}
```

Or use `var self = this` workaround:

```
var self = this;
accessController_onNavAccessSelected(event: ng.IAngularEvent, accessViewModel: soft.data.AccessViewModel): void {
    console.log(self);
}
```

Or you can force to specify exactly `this`, you needed, with the help of `bind`:

```
this.$rootScope.$on('accessController_onNavAccessSelected', this.accessController_onNavAccessSelected.bind(this));
```