# Setting an undefined property in a typescript class

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a class that looks something like this

```
export class TestScreen extends Component<any, LoginScreenState> {
  private wallet: Wallet;

  async connect() {
    this.wallet = WAL.accessContext.initWallet(getWalletProviders()[0]);
    ....
  }

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.connect}>Connect</button>
            <br />
        </div>
    );
    }
}
```

I get the following error

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot set property 'wallet' of undefined
```

I understand that error, but I'm not sure what the correct pattern to use here is. I only want to set that value value when connect() is run.

I don't want to initialize the object to some garbage and then replace it ether. Feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: How are you invoking `connect`? Do you have an instance of the class that you're using it with?

Comment: I think Silvio is on to something here, the message suggests that "this" is undefined which usually means that the function has been called from another context. If you change the async connect() { ... } to async connect = () => { ... } (which binds to the context of the class) it might work. But more information is needed here to be sure.

Comment: Thanks guys, I updated the code to show how I'm calling connect. I have a button which is on the render() output.

Comment: Maybe try doing `onClick={() => this.connect()}` instead of `onClick={this.connect}`. I think it should fix your context problem.

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you, that is exactly the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `this` can be quite tricky in TypeScript. The `this` behaviour actually comes from JavaScript, as @ecraig12345 pointed out in the comments. When passing a reference of a method, there are some cases where you lose the context. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627988/5818232) provides a great explanation. You can also learn more about that in the [TypeScript documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript).

In your case, I suggest you do the following. It's a pretty common syntax.

```
onClick={e => this.connect(e)}
```

Comment: Just as a note, you can make the type checker catch problems like this with an explicit `this` signature on the function (`async connect(this: TestScreen)`). You can find more about how Typescript handles `this` on [the website](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this).

Comment: One clarification, the behavior of `this` is actually a part of JavaScript, not TypeScript. (but also affects TS since it compiles down to JS)