# How to access "this" scope and a private method in a jquery callback?

Tags: typescript

Consider the code below.  In the click callback I am trying to access the `color` css property of `this`.  At the same time I need to call a private method `setResponsiveClass`, which can only be achieved by using `this.setResponsiveClass`.  The code won't compile obviously because `this` is scoped to event handler.

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor {    
    $('.someclass').on('click', function() {

      var color = $(this).css('color');
      console.log(color);          

      this.setResponsiveClass();
    });
 }        

  private setResponsiveClass() {
    console.log('hello')
  }
}
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627988/9382) provides ways to achieve either event scoping (by keeping the current code) or class scoping (by converting to a fat arrow syntax).

How can I access both `this` from the event scope and the private method in the same function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger this with this way

### solution 1.

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor {    
    $('.someclass').on('click', = () => {

      var color = $(this).css('color');
      console.log(color);          

      this.setResponsiveClass();
    });
 }        

  private setResponsiveClass() {
    console.log('hello')
  }
}
```

### solution 2.

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor {    

    var self = this;  <====

    $('.someclass').on('click', function() {

      var color = $(this).css('color');
      console.log(color);          

      self.setResponsiveClass();  <====
    });
 }        

  private setResponsiveClass() {
    console.log('hello')
  }
}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Solution 1 doesn't work because because the TypeScript compiler redefines this as _this=this.  Solution 2 does work, but we are basically back to JavaScript tricks.  I was hoping TypeScript would have a more elegant solution to this problem.