# Can i pass outside function to RxJs subscribe?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

If i check RxJS subscribe method I can see that:

```
    subscribe(next?: (value: T) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
```

so I write example init function like this:

```
  private init(): void{
this.dataBaseService.fetchPersons().subscribe(
   (persons: Person[]) => {
    this.behaviorSubject.next(persons);
    this.subject.next(persons);
  },
  error => console.error(error),
  () => console.log('Complete!')
);
```

}

is it required in Typescript to provide lambda function to argument? Can I create function somewhere else and provide it as argument?

for example this function:

```
       (persons: Person[]) => {
    this.behaviorSubject.next(persons);
    this.subject.next(persons);
  }
```

create in upper class and then provide it as argument.

Ok so I tried to create a method inside a class:

```
  someFunction( persons: Person[] ){
this.behaviorSubject.next(persons);
this.subject.next(persons);
```

}

and tried to pass it to init function

```
    private init2(): void {
  this.dataBaseService.fetchPersons().subscribe(
    this.someFunction(),
    error => void,
    () => console.log('Complete!');
  )
}
```

And I receive error:

```
An argument for 'persons' was not provided.
```

What kind of argument I have to provide if its initialisation of this upper method?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just try it? Yes you can.

Comment: yes, you just have to provide a callable function... it doesn't have to be a lambda function

Comment: You can! But be careful about your `this` :)

Comment: I have edited my post, I dont know what argument I should provide if its actually an initialistation

Comment: just pass it as `this.someFunction` without the `()`

Comment: its working!!! but I'm confused. will subject and behavior subjcet receive Persons argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your function without the `()` or it instantly gets called:

```
someFunction( persons: Person[]) {
    this.behaviorSubject.next(persons);
    this.subject.next(persons);
}
    
private init2(): void {
    this.dataBaseService.fetchPersons().subscribe(
        this.someFunction, // <- pass it without ()
        error => void,
        () => console.log('Complete!')
    )
}
```

Comment: Its working thank you! But i dont know how its working, will behaviorSubject and subject receive persons argument?

Comment: Yes it will. If you are unsure, or just want to write clearer code, you could also pass `person => this.someFunction(person)` instead of `this.someFunction` @DarkFurby

Comment: I'd be careful about that because the use of ```this``` inside the function might break in certain circumstances. I found that it's always better to declare your function as a field like ```someFunction = (...) => {...}``` when planning on using it as a variable/parameter

Comment: I have used both countless times and have never seen it break somehow, but I would be more than open to get shown otherwise- Do you have an example? @h0ss

Comment: Here is an example of this scoping gone bad, I guess in OPs example it will be fine but it is always useful to know the limitations of certain approaches https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627138/typescript-this-scoping-issue-when-called-in-jquery-callback

Comment: Thanks for the link! That's an interesting problem, but as you said yourself - probably not much applicable to OPs question. Thanks though @h0ss